# kibana-4.3 how to develop plugin

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch, kibana-4

Where can I find a developer guide to kibana, that explain me how the system work and all the things i need to know for developing kibana plugin?

Or if someone could publish snippets of sample plugin.

I've started cloning statusPage plugin, but I don't want to do revers engineering to understand the platform.

On the website, the is no type of developer manual.

Thank you

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The problem is that  need to build a kibana plugin, but the unique things I'm able to do is to clone another existing plugin and change just few parameters. So i need a guide that help me to build my own plugin also expalining how kibana works.
On the kibana website, there is only a user-guide but not a developer-guide. So someone can help me with useful material?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official answer](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3424) from 6+ months ago seems to be "don't":

> We're working to develop an external API but would caution you away
>   from making custom changes as things still move pretty fast and
>   internal APIs are likely to change even in patch versions.

[Also](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4704), "there are no public plugin APIs right now" (8/2015)

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to the following links to learn How to develop Kibana Plugins:-

> http://logz.io/blog/kibana-visualizations/
>
> https://www.timroes.de/2015/12/02/writing-kibana-4-plugins-basics/

Answer (score 2):

Hard to find any information to date. I recommend you to look at the plugin generator released some days ago:

[Generator Kibana Plugin Structure](https://github.com/elastic/generator-kibana-plugin)

There are two plugins I found where you can have a look at the code to understand the structure. The first is the Sense plugin, the second Timelion. Timelion matches more to the structure of the generator.

[Sense Github](https://github.com/elastic/sense)

[Timelion GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/timelion)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest understanding plugin structure and code for traffic plugin (https://github.com/sbeyn/kibana-plugin-traffic-sg) which would be one of the simplest plugins to understand and you could directly add it to your installed plugin folder in kibana and see it working.

Other than that I would also suggest you do read timroes blogs (https://www.timroes.de/2015/12/02/writing-kibana-4-plugins-basics/) for developing kibana plugins

and last I would also suggest using elasticsearch discussion forum for kibana related issues as well for quicker responses:
https://discuss.elastic.co